# Помогите!!! Не могу найти и исправить ошибку в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Модерация не принимает нижеприведенное предложение, ссылаясь на пунктационную ошибку. Я найти эту ошибку не могу. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

"Например, если на шестерне маркировка "В", то и новую запчасть выбираем с той же маркировкой"

Comment: Это где же такие строгие модераторы?

Comment: А точку в конце предложения Вы сейчас опустили?

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать такой вариант: "Если, например,  на шестерне маркировка "В", то и новую запчасть выбираем с той же маркировкой."

Вообще говоря, вводное слово не должно соединяться с союзом, например:   "Высокие портьеры темно-красного шелка висели у каждого окна, вероятно, чтобы закрыть его в течение часов дневного света".

Но в этом примере придаточное предложение стоит после главного, да и трудно в художественных текстах  найти такой вариант, чтобы вводное слово стояло в начале предложения перед подчинительным союзом.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, все гораздо проще. Модератор-автомат, видимо, воспринимает маркировку "В" как прямую речь в кавычках, и у него ломается мозг. Попробуйте изменить "В" на слово "икс", может быть даже без кавычек, и если всё пройдет, то и славно. Окажется, что это вопрос не по русскому языку.

Comment: Интересная история. Чем все закончилось?

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте точку в конце предложения.

Answer (score 0):

В конце предложения, за кавычками, нужно поставить точку.

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем за отклики. Как оказалось нужно было расковычить "В". )))Vadimych74 - Вы оказались ближе всех к истине.
Самые суровые модераторы работают на Текст ру )))